# Showing "Cannot find the requested object" exception

Tags: c#, x509certificate, x509certificate2

tried to generate the certificate from pem file.
Got exception mentioned above.

```
string csrPath = @"C:\Users\h541525\csrgenerate.pem";
string csr = File.ReadAllText(csrPath);
byte[] certificateBytes = GetBytesFromPem(csr);
X509Certificate2 certificate1 = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes); //got exception here`
```

How to solve this?

tried to generate the certificate from pem file.
Got exception mentioned above.

Comment: There's not enough detail here, for example what is `GetBytesFromPem`?

Comment: Try : X509Certificate2 certificate1 = new X509Certificate2(filename);

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `X509Certificate2(Byte[])` constructor expects DER-encoded bytes, while your file is saved as base64 string with PEM header and footer. In your case, you need to use another constructor that accepts path to a certificate file which accepts certificate files in various formats: `X509Certificate2(String)`.

Comment: in this function byte[] certificateBytes = GetBytesFromPem(csr);
i am getting pem contents and converting to der and i amgetting the exception

Comment: I have no idea what `GetBytesFromPem` is. The problem can be there, but the code is unknown.

Comment: Can you pls tell how CA extracts data from csr data and genrate certificates using x509? It will be more helpful if its in code.